# E-mail with obfuscated code / no trace in e-mail server

Tags: email, shellcode

I've got a situation where one of my clients sent me an e-mail with what appears to be obfuscated shell code. The really bizarre thing here is that I see no trace of this e-mail showing up in the mail server and the headers are almost blank.

Has anyone seen anything like this? Is this a cause for concern?

The (obfuscated code) is listed below.

```
-----Original Message-----
From: 
Sent: Thursday, January 17, 2013 11:30 AM
Subject: 

----boundary_64354_0d34ef45-e6e9-4610-8382-1fdd2040fd60
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

**BASE64 data** 

----boundary_64354_0d34ef45-e6e9-4610-8382-1fdd2040fd60
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PGh0bWw+DQogIDxoZWFkPg0KICAgIDxNRVRBIGh0dHAtZXF1aXY9IkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIg
```

(truncated)

Comment: A note: we removed the original edit to this posting because the encoded data contained an individual's airline flight confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not obfuscated code, it is just base64. You can decode it on this [site](http://www.base64decode.org/). It is an email containing a flight reservation confirmation. I don't know if it should be publicly available, maybe you should edit your post. You can read more about email encoding [here](http://email.about.com/cs/standards/a/mime.htm).

Comment: Wow that's very interesting - thanks for the post.

Comment: if you know python, you could also do `"encodedstring".decode("base64")`, I prefer that to websites as it's quicker and at least I know my base64 isn't being stored somewhere :-)